# uwp приложение занимает много памяти (утечка памяти)

Tags: c#, uwp, память

Пишу uwp приложение. В качестве меню для навигации (переходам по станицам) использую splitview. Копировать на каждой станице один и тоже код splitview не хочу из-за памяти. Нашел способ как сделать его на все станицы сразу - создал UserControl (отдельный файл xaml). Туда поместил splitview с кодом. На страницах где он мне нужен, в коде xaml пишу -

```
<SplitView x:Name="Menu">
  <local:MenuX/>
</SplitView>
```

Все работает прекрасно, но проблема в том, что когда я перехожу со страницы на страницу, то новая страница просто перекрывает старую. То есть память предыдущей страницы и всех её элементов не освобождается. 
Вот часть кода, в которой происходит переход на другую страницу

```
private void Home_SelectionChanged (object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (Home.SelectedIndex == 0)
    myFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
}
```

Собственно на странице с самим splitview я создаю frame

```
<Frame x:Name="myFrame"/>
```

Пробовал использовать

```
private void Home_SelectionChanged (object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (Home.SelectedIndex == 0)
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage)); ///Frame вместо myFrame
}
```

Но выдает ошибку что для не статического  метода требуется ссылка на объект.
Может кто то знает как решить эту проблему и освобождать память, или как то по другому сделать общий splitview, или как получить ссылку на объект (как я понимаю на саму страницу).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы SplitView был один на все страницы надо использовать его в качестве шелла. Примеры вот:

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Windows/tree/master/SplitViewSample это с помощью Prism.

https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10 - это основано на Prism, но без него.